# Java Restful API..The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

I am trying to work with Java Restful Api..But when i run the application the server send back Resource not found..I try hard But i cann't solve that..I use Eclipse IDE And Tomcat 7 server.

................Web.Xml file.....................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>RestfullAndAngularJSTest</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

...........Product.java file.....................

```
package entities;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;;

@XmlRootElement(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double price;

    @XmlElement
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Product(String id, String name, double price) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Product() {

    }

}
```

...........ApplicationConfig.java file....................

```
package productWS;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(productWS.ProductRestFull.class);
    }

}
```

.........ProductRestFull.java file......

```
package productWS;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import java.util.*;
import entities.*;

@Path("product")
public class ProductRestFull {
    @GET
    @Path("findall")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Product> findAll() {
        List<Product> result = new ArrayList<Product>();
        result.add(new Product("P01", "Name1", 1000.00));
        result.add(new Product("P02", "Name2", 1050.00));
        result.add(new Product("P01", "Name3", 2000.00));
        result.add(new Product("P01", "Name4", 3000.00));
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is the     URL:http://localhost:8080/RestfullAndAngularJSTest/rest/product/findall

Answer (score 0):

You need to include implementation JAX-RS API i.e jersey jar to build restful webservices.

Download jersey jar from below.

https://jersey.java.net/download.html

Add following servlet entry to **web.xml**.

```
<servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
            <param-value>com.expertwebindia.rest</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
      </servlet>  
      <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
      </servlet-mapping>
```

You can see more detail about [JAX-RS tutorial](http://www.expertwebindia.com/jax-rs-crud-application-example/)

Comment: I already followed your instruction but it still not working...can anyone help me??

Comment: Have you added the servlet entry to web.xml. You need to jersey.config.server.provider.packages param to your package name "productWS".
Share web.xml entry here and error you are getting.

Comment: server send me the same message "The requested resource is not available."

Comment: Share web.xml entry here.

Comment: Check the updation on web.xml here
http://pastebin.com/4uCtQJ9B
YOu can also put issue here.
http://www.expertwebindia.com/support/

Comment: There was wrong package for <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  configured in your web.xml.
For JSON output you need gson.jar in your WEB-INF/lib. Check above tutorial added.